# How do I use a software SDL_Renderer correctly while resizing the window?

Tags: c, sdl-2

I'm not sure how to use a software `SDL_Renderer` to render to a window while resizing that window. For example, I expect the following code to constantly display a fully black window even as the uses resizes the window. Instead, when the user resizes the window, it's not filled with black, you get kind of "streaks" of black against a transparent background.

I'm sure I could cobble something together with catching resize events, maybe using `SDL_RenderFilleRect()` instead of `SDL_RenderClear()`, but fundamentally I just don't know what I should be doing at all. Should I be freeing the `SDL_Surface` and getting an entirely new surface and renderer every time the window resizes? Should I be calling `SDL_RenderSetViewport()`?

```
#include <SDL.h>

int main()
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "Main Window",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        600,
        600,
        SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE
    );

    SDL_Surface *window_surface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
    
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateSoftwareRenderer(window_surface);

    SDL_Event event;
    bool quit = false;
    while (!quit)
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            switch (event.type)
            {
                case SDL_QUIT:
                quit = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
        
        SDL_Delay(1000 / 60);
    }

    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does `SDL_CreateRenderer()` with `SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE` work any differently?

Comment: The [`SDL_GetWindowSurface()` docs](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/main/include/SDL_video.h#L1110-L1131) say that the returned surface is invalidated by resizes & to call it again for a new one.  And also to not use it with the rendering API.